# PyQt5 window not opening on show() when parent window is specified

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have defined a simple main window and second pop-up window. When I call the MainWindow.create_new_window() method, the SecondWindow does not show up as a new window but its QLabel is created within the MainWindow instance. Here's the code:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QLabel, QWidget, QVBoxLayout

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.second_window = None

        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.new_window_button = QPushButton('New Window', self)
        self.new_window_button.clicked.connect(self.create_new_window)

        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.new_window_button)

    def create_new_window(self):
        if self.second_window is None:
            self.second_window = SecondWindow(self)
        self.second_window.show()


class SecondWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SecondWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.hello_label = QLabel('Hello I am the second window.', self)

        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.hello_label)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwin = MainWindow()
    mainwin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I create the second window without specifying the MainWindow instance as the parent (`self.second_window = SecondWindow()`), it opens as expected. Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a QWidget that has a parent implies that the widget will be placed inside the parent, so you observe that behavior.

If you want it to be a window then you must activate the flag [Qt::Window](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum)

```py
# ...
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

# ...
class SecondWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SecondWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | Qt.Window) # <---
# ...
```

Other options is to use a QDialog that is a type of widget that by default already has that flag activated and whose objective is to ask the user for information.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I knew I was missing something, but I could not find what.

Comment: I recommend you check the following example https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-windowflags-example.html, If you want to see the version in python then download [the source code](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Downloads/PyQt5/5.12.2/PyQt5_gpl-5.12.2.zip) of pyqt5 and check the file examples/widgets/windowflags.py

Answer (score 1):

From documentation:

> If parent is 0, the new widget becomes a window. If parent is another widget, this widget becomes a child window inside parent. The new widget is deleted when its parent is deleted.

When I run your code, I get that new widget inside of the main one - as is described in documentation.

So basically, you should set parent to a `QWidget` only if you indend to use it as a window's widget (insert it in a layout, or use it as central widget etc.); if you want to use it as-is you don't need a parent.

If you need your widget to have a parent and be a separate window, better idea may be to use `QDialog` instead of `QWidget`. Just make your `SecondWindow` class subclass `QDialog` instead and you're good to go.

Example code (I've changed both your Windows to `QDialog`):

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QLabel, QApplication, QDialog
class MainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.second_window = None

        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.new_window_button = QPushButton('New Window', self)
        self.new_window_button.clicked.connect(self.create_new_window)

        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.new_window_button)

    def create_new_window(self):
        if self.second_window is None:
            self.second_window = SecondWindow(self)
        # set second window as modal, because MainWindow is QDialog/QWidget.
        self.setModal(True)
        self.second_window.show()


class SecondWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SecondWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.hello_label = QLabel('Hello I am the second window.', self)

        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.hello_label)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwin = MainWindow()
    mainwin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I do need the parent. My end goal is to have a child window which is WindowModal, meaning it blocks interaction with its parent window.

Comment: Your solution then would probably be better with `QMainWindow` instead of `QDialog`/`QWidget`. In this case (as written), you have to add `self.setModal(True)` in `create_new_window()`. I've updated my answer to add second window modality.

Comment: self.setModal() is useless if it doesn't show up as a new window in the first place.

Comment: My answer is based on your code - I've just changed both windows to `QDialog` subclasses where it works.

Answer (score -1):

In your imported packages import that staff:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QLabel
```

Comment: All of my imports are correct. I left them off the question because I thought that was self explanatory, my mistake. I will edit the question.